# How can I hide my implementation with interfaces and still build upon classes with inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

I like the idea of using interfaces to hide my implementation details. I also really enjoying using inheritance as a way to build upon my previously created classes. How can I get both of these benefits to coexist together? Here is an example of my problem:

```
object.h

class object {
    protected:
        //stuff that should be available to derived classes
        virtual void    derivedHelper    () = 0;

    public:
        //stuff that should be available to the client
        virtual object* create           () = 0;
        virtual void    mainTask         () = 0;
}

object.cpp

class objectPriv : public object {
    private:
        //implementation specific details and members
    protected:
        void derivedHelper () {
             //some stuff
        }
    public:
        objectPriv() { }

        object* create () {
            return(new objectPriv());
        }
        void mainTask () {
            //more stuff
        }
}

superObject.h

class superObject : public object {             //problem #1
    public:
        //stuff that should be available to the client
        virtual superObject* create  () = 0;
}

superObject.cpp

class superObjectPriv : public superObject {    //problem #2
    private:
        //the magic behind super object

    public:
        superObjectPriv() { }

        superObject* create () {
            return(new superObjectPriv());
        }

        void mainTask () {
            object::mainTask();                 //problem #3
            object::derivedHelper();            //problem #4
            //super extra stuff
        }
}
```

So you can see here that this won't compile.

I could implement the pure virtuals of object for superObject, but that defeat the purpose of deriving from object. I don't want to duplicate the implementation, I want to build on it.

I could change superObject to derive from objectPriv, but then I would be exposing my implementation details. I want to hide everything specific about objectPriv from everybody.

I can't think of any way to achieve this. I have a bad feeling that it might not be possible, but I have my fingers crossed that you folks will have some clever trick for me :)

Thanks
Les

Comment: Search for "Pimpl idiom".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks for the suggestion. Pimpl seems like it has it's own drawbacks though; like a heap allocation and additional layer of indirection. I don't know if I am willing to make that sacrifice or not. I realize that interfaces add a layer of indirection as well, but that is also something I am still struggling to accept. I don't currently use the interface design; I use nested classes instead. This keeps everything private and I can still inline methods, but it creates some very messy public headers :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the mixin pattern?  It is a way to add shared implementation to  multiple classes.  One defines a template class which derives from it's argument.  You could do that with the the common behavior of ObjectPriv and SuperObjectPriv:

```
template <typename ParentT>
class CommonFunctionalityMixin
: public ParentT   // this is the magic line that makes it a mixin
{
    public:
        typedef ParentT parent_type;

        virtual void mainTask()      { /* implementation */ }
        virtual void derivedHelper() { /* implementation */ }
};

class ObjectPriv
: public CommonFunctionalityMixin<object> // which derives from object
{
    public:
        typedef CommonFunctionalityMixin<object> parent_type;

        virtual object* create()     { return new ObjectPriv; }
        // virtual void mainTask() defined in CommonFunctionalityMixin
        // virtual void derivedHelper() defined in CommonFunctionalityMixin
};

class SuperObjectPriv
: public CommonFunctionalityMixin<superObject> // which derives from superObject
{
    public:
        typedef CommonFunctionalityMixin<object> parent_type;

        virtual object* create()     { return new SuperObjectPriv; }

        // now we override CommonFunctionalityMixin's mainTask() with super's
        virtual void mainTask()
        {
            parent_type::mainTask();
            parent_type::derivedHelper();
        }
};
```